# video call or voice call with adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, animate-cc

I want to make a *social connections* type of app with Adobe Air to help people find friendships.

**Problem:**
Is there any way to make video calls or voice calls in my app with Adobe Air (send audio/video bytes over the internet )?

Comment: Not clear.. You mean via sending audio/video bytes over internet?.. Or using (mobile) system tools (_eg:_ signal tower connection for voice calls)?

Comment: Yes, I want to send audio/video bytes over internet

Comment: Then get your audio/video bytes and send them over internet by using [**sockets**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=M3rdXN7sN8yk1fAPsvGbqAc&q=as3+socket+tutorial).

Comment: @VC.One I doubt **Socket** is the best solution, I think that (Client A (**Microphone**, **Camera**) -> **NetStream** -> **NetConnection**) -> (Client B **NetConnection** -> **NetStream** -> (**Video**)) is a solution intended exactly for this. Although is it easy to find only server-driven examples, I think it is possible to do it directly peer-to-peer.

Comment: @Organis the Asker is welcome to try anything. All I heard is _sending bytes over internet_ for which TCP (sockets) is a valid option (think Icecast streams etc). When I said "not clear" that should be a hint to Asker to expand on the topic. We haven't even moved on to the **NetStream** part yet.. I want to know where/how they encode these "audio/video bytes". PS: In one project I worked on they didn't even use any video/audio codecs, they just used custom system of LZ4 compression on BitmapData and PCM/raw audio, but they re-used the **I** and **P** frame concept from most other video codecs.

Comment: @YoonesMashayekhi does your app involve any server? I mean the user's must make profiles, right?, so are these user's data stored in some online server or what? Can "friendships" mean even multi-user (conference/group) calls are an option to your users or is it one-to-one only?

Comment: @VC.One Yes, in my all users involve to a server, and first of all they make a profile, and my video call is one to one only

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. Both through a server application (Adobe Media Server i.e.), or in peer-to-peer (for which you will need a server application to handshake anyway, but not as a data gateway). AWS offers virtual servers with Adobe Media Server pre-installed.